# Cards in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'card' of undefined.

- If i remove the content `className={classes.card}` it works fine.
- But without classes, I'm unable to use Const Styles.

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

const styles = {
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 200,
  },
};

function SimpleMediaCard(props) {
 const classes = props.classes;
 return (
   <div>
     <Card className={classes.card}>
       <CardMedia
         title="Contemplative Reptile"
       />
       <CardContent>
        <Typography type="headline" component="h2">
           Lizard
         </Typography>
         <Typography component="p">
           Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species, ranging
            across all continents except Antarctica
         </Typography>
       </CardContent>
       <CardActions>
         <Button dense color="primary">
           Share
         </Button>
         <Button dense color="primary">
           Learn More
         </Button>
       </CardActions>
     </Card>
   </div>
 );
}

SimpleMediaCard.propTypes = {
 classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export { SimpleMediaCard };
```

Comment: are you passing the `classes` to component `SimpleMediaCard` in props? it should be like this: `<SimpleMediaCard classes={card: {....}}>`

Comment: where are you rendring `SimpleMediaCard` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `className` should contain a string, eg `className="btn btn-large"

The property `style` expects an object, eg `style={{maxWidth: 345}}`

So I think you really meant to say `<Card style={styles.card}`

Comment: Thank you so much  for the answer and explanation. It worked with with <Card style={styles.card} :-)

Answer (score 0):

What's missing is "withStyles":

```
SimpleMediaCard = withStyles(styles)(SimpleMediaCard)
```

This will pass the classes prop to your component and the error will go away